# Linked Trezor to an empty keystore file, how do I change it?

Tags: myetherwallet, trezor

I generated a wallet using MyEtherWallet, first on the test network Rinkeby, then one on the real network. I copied my keystore json files for both. When connecting to my trezor wallet, I opened the empty test accounts' keystore file by accident. When I try to open MyEtherWallet with trezor, it automatically opens the empty account, so I can't transfer my eth that is in a different account with a different keystore file.

But it appears that trezor can only store one keystore file? There is no option to delete the wrong keystore file and enter the right one? I assume I can format Trezor and start over, but I already have some bitcoin in there, so I want to know if there is a simpler way than sending btc out, formatting trezor and resending everything.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to read [an in-depth guide](https://blog.trezor.io/trezor-integration-with-myetherwallet-3e217a652e08) as to how Trezor works with MyEtherWallet. That's really the only thing I can suggest as for steps on how to use it go.

You've asked several different questions here. First off, let me clarify what Trezor is. Trezor is a hardware wallet, meaning that the private key (keystore/utc/json file) is...non-existent. You can't transfer a private key to Trezor if you only have the keystore/utc/json file. Instead, the device itself stores the private key it generates when it starts up.

What does this mean? It means that no matter what wallet you have now, you need to send the ether stored in that wallet to Trezor, using MyEtherWallet. You can't "replace" the "utc/json" file on Trezor -- and Trezor doesn't store one. You have to send your ether, through the Ethereum network, to the hardware wallet that you now own.

The basis of all security of hardware wallets is that it's impossible for you to get the private key off of the device, and it's also impossible to directly access the private key or replace it on the device.

---

The short version of the [steps you need to follow are](https://myetherwallet.github.io/knowledge-base/migration/moving-from-private-key-to-trezor-hardware-wallet.html):

1. Go to MyEtherWallet.
2. Click "Send Ether & Tokens".
3. CLick TREZOR.
4. Plug in your Trezor, and then hit export.
5. Select the ethereum address you want to interact with and copy the address.
6. Transfer funds from your pre-existing wallets (the ones you generated with Rinkeby, the ones you have on the real network (they can actually be used for both)) to any Trezor address you prefer.
7. Your tokens and ether are now stored on the Trezor device.